# How to exclude directories in find OUTPUT

Tags: find

This is surprisingly hard to search for because all results are for excluding directories in the search.

I just want to exclude directories from the output. For instance:

```
>find ./ -size +0
./directory
./directory/afileinthere.txt
```

I want this output:

```
>find ./ -size +0
./directory/afileinthere.txt
```

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 4):

[The other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1046224/432690) points to the `-type` operand but it's not really obvious how you *exclude* directories with it. You need `!`, it's like this:

- `-type d` matches directories only.
- `! -type d` matches everything but directories.

So your command should be:

```
find . ! -type d -size +0
```

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at the -type option of find in the manual:

```
   -type c
          File is of type c:

          b      block (buffered) special

          c      character (unbuffered) special

          d      directory

          p      named pipe (FIFO)

          f      regular file

          l      symbolic link; this is never true if the -L option or the -fol‐
                 low  option  is  in effect, unless the symbolic link is broken.
                 If you want to search for symbolic links when -L is in  effect,
                 use -xtype.

          s      socket

          D      door (Solaris)
```

Comment: I tried, but honestly, that man page is simply awful. I didn't have time to read a novel. -type is exactly what I needed though. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Hardly anyone reads manuals from alpha to omega. Rather, using / one can search within the manual for (regular) expressions which may lead to the required portion. Of course, some imagination is needed for the right expression but the case is similar to using google.